# How to preview rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, preview

A website is shared to me on github. I'm working on it, but I can't do modifications on the actual site page yet. I need to see how the changes I make look like.

How can I have a live preview from rails? I was used to use xampp for the html/css stuff. Is there anything similar to that? If not, what are my choices?

Comment: you will write code in your development machine and test every features, and then push code to server. So development environment, in your own computer good place to preview it.

Comment: Unless you push you work to github you can make all change you need and test in rails server without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual workflow is to setup a development environment on your local machine. The tools you will need for this are roughly:

- git, to clone the github repository to your local machine
- ruby (what version you need depends on the project), preferably you use a version manager such as rvm or rbenv
- the correct database (again depending on your project, e.g. mysql or postgresql)

Once you have a ruby version installed, the first step will be to run 'bundle' to install all dependent ruby libraries. If that was successful you can configure your database in a file that either exists already or should be added: config/database.yml in which you configure the database connection.

You would use the command 'rake db:create db:migrate' to setup the database according to the projects migrations (=> specifying the database layout).

You might want to make yourself a bit familiar with ruby on rails, by following some good beginners tutorial. In the official rails guides that would be: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

It is not as 'out-of-the-box' as you might be used to from xampp , so there might be a bunch of pitfalls in the way (especially if you're running on windows and not linux / mac).

It is hard to give you a complete walkthrough without knowing the application and your system.

Depending on who's developing the application you might also ask them to provide you with a VM, e.g. using a tool called 'vagrant' to simplify the setup for you. You will still need to get more familiar with git, in case you aren't yet.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can first keep your apache on xampp running normal. 
Go to command prompt if you are on windows. Go to the root of your application on your computer. 
Then run 
rails server
To open the server. If you done all that correctly it should open on your browser at 
Localhost:3000 
Then you can take it from there.